# Put individual words and underlined groups of words into arrays

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, parallel-processing

I've got a program that iterates through text and puts words and underlined groups of words into arrays...the code is as follows:

```
    //loop for all text in rich edit control
for(int i = 0; i < text.GetLength(); i++)
{
    rEditCtrl.SetSel(i, i + 1); //from start to end character
    rEditCtrl.GetSelectionCharFormat(cf);

    if(cf.dwEffects & CFE_UNDERLINE) //check whether underline character
    {
        if(!groupMode) {
            groupMode = true;
        }

        isSpace = false;

        if(!word.IsEmpty()) {
            std::pair <CString,bool> group;
            group = std::make_pair(word,false);
            groups.push_back(group);
            word = "";
        }

        underlined = underlined + rEditCtrl.GetSelText();

    }
    else {
        if(groupMode) {

            rEditCtrl.SetSel(i, i + 1); //from start to end character
            if(rEditCtrl.GetSelText() == " ") {
                underlined = underlined + rEditCtrl.GetSelText();                           
            }
            else {
                word = word + rEditCtrl.GetSelText();
            } 
                groupMode = false;



                if(!underlined.IsEmpty()) {
                    std::pair <CString,bool> group;
                    group = std::make_pair(underlined,true);
                    groups.push_back(group);
                    underlined = "";
                }


        }
        else {
            if(!isSpace) {
                rEditCtrl.SetSel(i, i + 1); //from start to end character

                if(rEditCtrl.GetSelText() == " ") {
                    isSpace = true;                  
                }
                else if(rEditCtrl.GetSelText() == "\r") {
                    if(!word.IsEmpty()) {
                        std::pair <CString,bool> group;
                        group = std::make_pair(word,false);
                        groups.push_back(group);
                        word = "";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(word == "\r") {
                        std::pair <CString,bool> group;
                        group = std::make_pair(word,false);
                        groups.push_back(group);
                        word = "";
                    }
                }
                word = word + rEditCtrl.GetSelText();


            }
            else if(isSpace) {
                rEditCtrl.SetSel(i, i + 1); //from start to end character

                if(rEditCtrl.GetSelText() != " ") {
                    isSpace = false;

                    if(!word.IsEmpty() && !AllSpaces(word)) {
                        std::pair <CString,bool> group;
                        group = std::make_pair(word,false);
                        groups.push_back(group);
                        word = "";
                    }

                }

                word = word + rEditCtrl.GetSelText();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is an obvious way to improve the efficiency of this code that i'm missing, or do i have use parrallelism for any gains in speed...also if parallelism is the way to go....how would i approach the problem? I can only think of dividing the text in two, start from the beginning and end and meet in the middle? What do you think?

Comment: There is a little bug in the loop command. It has to read `for(int i = 0; i < text.GetLength()-1`

Comment: I'd find out the number of processor cores, split the string in exactly this number of parts, and start worker threads accordingly. But optimizing a single rich edit control processing seems a bit overdone to me. I'd try to do some leverage at another point in the code.

Comment: First Thomiel, thanks for replying. Why is that a bug in the loop command? i.e. can you explain the purpose of minusing 1? Secondly, would optimizing the code above for parrallelism increase performance or not? Reason why I am thinking of going down this route is because everywhere else in the code runs fine....it is just one specific function of the program(involving the above code), which when used runs slowly.

Comment: Oops, no, I was wrong about the bug. Sorry. I'd rather try to find a workaround for this function than to rely on pure horsepower to speed things up.

Comment: You could try disabling redraw so that the continual shifting of the selection does not cause the rich edit to redraw each time.

Comment: Thanks user, that sounds like a good idea.